# Cache drop if query has WHERE Clause

Tags: sqldependency

I am using SqlDependency and CacheManager class(Enterprise library Cachcing block) to create a cache in one of vb.net project.

I have registerd

```
OnDependencyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
```

method to get the notification back from Sql Server 2005.

Now the problem is, if the query does not contains any WHERE clause then cache gets created successfully but if I add a where clause in my query then OnDependencyChanged() method gets notification as soon as cache is created.

I need suggestion whether it is possible to have a WHERE clause in the query that is being used for caching. 
My query is (with WHERE Clause):

```
SELECT [DATABASES_ID]  
      ,[DATABASENAME]
      ,[SERVERNAME]
  FROM [dbo].[DATABASES]
  WHERE datediff(dd,getdate(), [DATECREATED]) <=0
```

Thanks
Brijesh

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article outlying the limitations of SQLDepenency queries

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh.aspx

Specifically of Note:

> The statement must not use any
>   nondeterministic functions, including
>   ranking and windowing functions.

GETDATE() being one such function.